# A question about HOD[A] and HOD(A)

Tags: set-theory

HOD[A] (the class of sets hereditarily ordinal definable from $A$ where $A$ is some set) is known to be a transitive model of ZFC.
HOD(A) (the class of sets hereditarily ordinal definable over $A$) is a transitive model of ZF only.

My question is: Is $A \in HOD[A]$? Is $A \in HOD(A)$?
if the answer to both questions is affirmative then this would lead to a contradiction since $A$ would be well ordered in $HOD[A]$ and not in $HOD(A)$.

What is going wrong?

Comment: You answered yourself. $A$ doesn't have to be in $HOD[A]$, take any example where $HOD(A)$ doesn't satisfy the axiom of choice.

Comment: Yes but isn't the set $X=\{u: u \in A\}$ in $HOD[A]$?

Comment: Are all the elements of $A$ ordinal definable from $A$?

Comment: Ok I got the point, thank you.